# Cannot create Kotlin object in Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have an Android app written in Java and I am trying to write a new feature in Kotlin. So I added a new Kotlin file and IntelliJ offered to setup the project for Kotlin.

The issue is that when trying to create a Kotlin object in Java, compilation fails with

> error: cannot find symbol constructor MyClassKt()

My Kotlin file (`MyClass.kt`):

```
 val SCREEN = 1;

 class MyClass() {
     fun hello(view: View) {
     } 
 }
```

In my app module:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
```

In my project module:

```
 classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

Invocation in Java:

```
 new MyClassKt();
```

Comment: your kotlin class seems to be MyClass and not MyObject ?!!

Comment: Did you apply Kotlin plugin? The `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'` on the top of your `app` module.

Comment: Could you add how you are invoking it from Java?

Comment: Thanks all! Updated the question, added the invocation, fixed the typos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Kotlin was creating a `MyClassKt` for the **file** (i.e. for accessing the SCREEN variable).

I just needed to use the normal class name and do `new MyClass()` (no `Kt` postfix).

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have these plugin on top in the app gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

And inside dependencies, should be like

```
dependencies {
def kotlin_version= "2.2.1"
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove brackets from kotlin class definition.

```
class MyClassXD {
    fun hello(view: View) {
    }
}
```

Probably Java got wild when it saw brackets in classname.

Comment: Brackets just says to add constructor without parameters, so it couldn't be a reason.

Comment: No argument constructor is created by default if no other constructor defined, so you do not need them.

Comment: Of course it is. And for example Android Studio will highlight it if you mention empty primary constructor, because it's useless to print that. I'm just trying to say it can't lead any error - it is just useless.